# Where and When should we use compile time macro concatenation?

Tags: c++, function, templates, macros, getter

I've seen this bit of code which I thought was great because it saved me from re-writing getter member functions.

```
#define GET(n_,N_)                      \
        template<typename T>            \
        const T &get##N_() const        \
        {                               \
            return n_;                  \
        }                               \
```

From what I know, Macros "write" code at compile time, therefore injecting the function template inside each class and because it's a template, it can compensate for any type.
So I ended up with this:

```
class Foo
{
   int m_a;
   GET(m_a,A)
};
```

then I used like this:

```
std::cout<< foo->getA<int>() <<std::endl;
```

My question is, WHEN and WHERE should we use macro templates?
And is there a way to NOT to specify the type when you are calling the getA member function? Is this because it's in a different namespace?

Comment: I vote for never.

Comment: Is your question "When should we use compile time macro concatenation?" or is your question "WHEN and WHERE should we use macro templates", or is your question "is there a way to NOT to specify the type when you are calling the getA member function", or what

Comment: what do you mean by "macro templates"? it seems as though you were convolving two completely unrelated concepts (macros and templates). You can use a macro to "generate" getter and setter functions, but honestly, I don't see why they should be *template* functions.

Comment: Anyway, just don't. You have some basic misconceptions, but it's unclear what. A good way to proceed is to just use basic language features and build up from solid ground, i.e. extending a basic repertoire bit by bit.

Comment: I vote for *opinion-based question* :)

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf To be honest all the above!

Comment: @ The Paramagnetic Croissant You use template to create a generic function. You use Macros to save code.

Comment: @Beero'clock But why do you need a generic function? `m_a` **is** an `int`. Why would the getter ever need to return something which is not `int`?

Comment: @ The Paramagnetic Croissant Because this means you can use this macro for any class you write! And classes usually contain other stuff, not just int. This was just an example. What if it's a vec3 or a matrix or other user-defined types.

Comment: You *must* specify the type when you call it, which you'll do way more often than you would write the function, so I predict the net savings, measured in keystrokes, will be negative for this trick. Besides, if you're routinely writing so many getters that it becomes a chore, you're Doing It Wrong(tm).

Comment: @ molbdnilo I'm guessing 1 or 2 getters per class. But what if you're working on a large code base with hundreds of classes? Or what if your writing a physics simulation which requires you to request for attributes from other classes? Do you friend them to access private data - No, because you break encapsulation, Or do you make them public - No again. So it's not a matter of "you're Doing It Wrong" because it depends on the application. I'm only asking about the technique, where and when should we use it.

Comment: @Beero'clock but you could make the type a macro argument…

Comment: @ The Paramagnetic Croissant You could! But then your macro function would get "copied" inside your code every time you include it in a class. What if someone decides to include it in the class or inherit from a class which uses it, but doesn't want to use it... Template get instantiated ONLY when they are being used! Macros don't! Apart from the fact that they are hidden from the compiler, they get copied everywhere! If that's what you need, then you might as well make it a globally accessible function (preferably inside a namespace)

Comment: @Beero'clock I'm not following this… if you define a template function "in line" i. e. inside the class definition in the header file (whether or not you are using macros for that doesn't matter), its code will be copied and pasted as well whenever you include the header file.

Comment: @ The Paramagnetic Croissant True! But it won't get instantiated unless it's being used!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest that mixing macros and templates will cause you to wind up with the weak points of both, as you've observed. The template return type of a function can never be inferred so you would always have to specify it. BUT luckily there's a solution, and it involves spelling the type into your macro:

```
#define GETTABLE_ATTR(type, name) \
private:
    type name_; \
public:
    type get_##name() const \
    { \
        return name_; \
    }
```

Whether using this macro is a good idea is still subjective - remember that you only write code once, and you're best served by writing it in the way that will both prevent mistakes as you write it AND will make maintaining the code easiest.

Comment: I have never seen such thing used before.. Interesting. However I think that if you use this inside a class definition, then you will have some very serious issues with memory alignment! Also you are open to duplication problems which might cause ambiguity errors. Finally, a comment is if you are to return a member data from a class, you should make it const both ways such as: const type get_##name() const.

Comment: @Beer o' clock `const` on a value return type has no effect and in fact generates a warning in g++.

Comment: No it doesn't! In fact it is the correct way of doing it! It is also mentioned in Effective C++ p. 125!!! The example he gives is in the lines of: const T &getSomething() const;

Comment: @Beer o' clock I think you're confusing returning by value and returning by reference. When returning by reference you're correct that adding `const` changes the meaning and const-correctness. When returning by value as my macro does it has no effect.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! If you are returning a copy, then const before the return type makes no sense. But when you're returning a reference, then you need it - thus my confusion. :)

Answer (score 1):

As also speaking for `c++14` there are still needs for having c macros involved.

I have two really often used macros in combination with MTP to get a a compile time constant which tells me if a method or attribute is existing in a class. This simply needs the name of the function which can not be given as parameter to a template. So I prepared that inside a c macro which "writes" my template which then can be used inside enable_if clause.

I personally dislike your idea from "automated getters", but this is only a question of taste.

As always in programming: If the thing helps, is not "undefined behaviour", is well documented in the code and could NOT be done with a more strait forward way the use of c macros is allowed. For me c macros are a kind of "self-defence" for not integrated language features.

Another popular example is enumeration with associated text for some kind of reflection or for serialisation.

The example to catch the existence of a method:

```
#define DECLARE_HAS_METHOD_FULL_SIGNATURE(NAME) \
template<typename, typename T>\
struct has_method_full_signature_ ## NAME {\
static_assert(\
        std::integral_constant<T, false>::value,\
        "Second template parameter needs to be of function type.");\
};\
\
\
template<typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>\
struct has_method_full_signature_ ## NAME <C, Ret(Args...)> {\
        template<typename T>\
        static constexpr auto check(T*)\
        -> typename\
        std::is_same<\
        decltype( std::declval<T>(). NAME ( std::declval<Args>()... ) ),\
        Ret   \
        >::type;  \
        \
        template<typename>\
        static constexpr std::false_type check(...);\
        \
        using type = decltype(check<C>(0));  \
        static constexpr bool value = type::value;\ 
}
```

EDIT: add some example code how to use this c-macro stuff here.

```
 #include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include "component/mytypes_traits.h"

DECLARE_HAS_METHOD_PARMS_ONLY(funny);

DECLARE_HAS_METHOD_FULL_SIGNATURE(f1);
DECLARE_HAS_METHOD_FULL_SIGNATURE(f2);
DECLARE_HAS_METHOD_FULL_SIGNATURE(f3);


class A { public: void funny() {} };

class B { public: void dummy() {} };

class C
{   
    public:
    int f1(int) { return 1;} 
    float f2(int,int) {return 2.0;}
    int f3() { return 1;} 
};  

int main()
{   
    std::cout << has_method_parms_only_funny<A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_method_parms_only_funny<B>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--" << std::endl;

    std::cout << has_method_full_signature_f1< C, int()>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_method_full_signature_f1< C, int(int)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_method_full_signature_f1< C, int(int,int)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--" << std::endl;

    std::cout << has_method_full_signature_f2< C, float()>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_method_full_signature_f2< C, float(int)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_method_full_signature_f2< C, float(int,int)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--" << std::endl;

    std::cout << has_method_full_signature_f3< C, int()>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_method_full_signature_f3< C, int(int)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_method_full_signature_f3< C, int(int,int)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your `has_method_full_signature` primary template is ill-formed as there is no specialization that would be valid. Just don't provide a definition for it.

Comment: I believe you are wrong. The check(...) is the false part and check(T*) evaluates to the good path. As I wrote in my answer, such code should be well documented. In the provided case it is not, so I have to check it again. Thanks :-)

Comment: Not the specialization on `Ret(Args...)`, the primary template with the `static_assert`.

Comment: @Barry: I wrote a simple test for my macros now and it looks ok for me. Maybe you can explain some more details or we should open a new question, because we are going a bit OT for the OP question here. But I hope I can catch your arguments. Maybe my code is broken so I like to get any helping advice!

Comment: OK, got it! I will dig into that the next days! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Klaus Thanks for your code example. I haven't coded with c++14 yet, but I get the picture. I would just like to comment on the "could NOT be done with a more strait forward way".. Sometimes a straight forward ways might imply code bloating - especially in Templates. Macros save the day when for example you write several partial class template specializations for a promotion trait class! I believe that there is no rule for when or where you should use Macros. In the end it depends on the application and design.